# Mean of non-zero elements in 3d array

Tags: matlab, vectorization, mean

I have this i x j x k 3d matrix (it's a movie). Without loops, I'm trying to take the mean of the non-zero positive elements in each ixj array and put these values into a 1x1xk matrix.

I've been searching for quite a while now, and although there's plenty of solutions to accomplish this for a 2d matrix, I can't for the life of me find a way to do it for a 3d matrix without using a loop.

Comment: So use a loop.  You'll spend more time waiting for a loop-free code than you'll save by using one.  Then get on with more challenging work, only come back and optimise this part of your code if it's necessary.  And the old adage that loop-free Matlab code outperforms the equivalent loop-using code is just that, an old adage.  Since about 2010b much loop-based code has been as fast as equivalent vectorised code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I already am using a loop and am now trying to optimize. I agree with you though.

Comment: If you already have a loop, please post the code for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you convert each image (frame) into an array:

```
% Remove negative and zero elements
A(A<=0) = 0;
% Convert each image into array
B = reshape(A,[Nimg,Nfrm]);
% Extract mean value of each image
C = mean(B,1);
```

where `Nimg` is the number of pixels in each image and `Nfrm` is the number of images.

If you don't want to include the non-zero and negative numbers in the mean denominator (as @Dan suggests), just scale the result with the following line:

```
C_Dan = C.*squeeze(Nimg./sum(sum(A>0))).';
```

Comment: How will setting all the 0 elements to 0 remove 0 elements?

Comment: @Dan My working assumption of the previous code is that he wants to calculate the mean intensity of each frame. Thus, the number of elements must be constant. For example, a 16x16 image with only one pixel of intensity 256 would have a mean value of 1 with my method and a value of 256 with yours. The user didn't specified this detail.

Comment: The user specified the "mean of the non-zero positive elements". So you must not count the elements with zero towards the mean calc. Each frame is different under this assumption.

Comment: Haha, thank you. I think this very simple question has already taken enough time from us.

Answer (score 2):

If you want no loops then how about just dividing the sum of each frame by the number of nonzero elements:

```
sum(sum(A))./sum(sum(A ~= 0))
```

To get rid of negative numbers, first run `A(A < 0) = 0` as pointed out by tashuhka

Comment: You code seems to include all the numbers in the nominator, and only the non-zero in the denominator.

Comment: @ EitanT, but negative number can affect. We assume that the encoding of the images doesnt contain negative numbers, but the users has never stated so.

Comment: @tashuhka I take your point about the negative numbers. In that case I agree that `A(A < 0) = 0` should be called first.