# Mean of the last two entries of non-zero elements in a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, mean

I have a (n by i by j) - 3D numpy array:`a_3d_array` (2 by 5 by 3)

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2],
    [0, 3, 3],
    [0, 0, 4]],

   [[1, 2, 3],
    [2, 2, 2],
    [3, 3, 3],
    [0, 4, 4],
    [0, 0, 5]]]).
```

For each column j in n, I want to extract the last 2 non-zero elements and calculate the mean, then put the results in a (n by j) array. What I currently do is using a for loop

```
import numpy as np

a_3d_array = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
                        [1, 1, 1],
                        [2, 2, 2],
                        [0, 3, 3],
                        [0, 0, 4]],
                       [[1, 2, 3],
                        [2, 2, 2],
                        [3, 3, 3],
                        [0, 4, 4],
                        [0, 0, 5]]])

aveCol = np.zeros([2,3])
for n in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        temp = a_3d_array[n,:,j]
        nonzero_array = temp[np.nonzero(temp)]
        aveCol[n, j] = np.mean(nonzero_array[-2:])
```

to get the desired results

```
print(aveCol)
[[1.5 2.5 3.5] [2.5 3.5 4.5]]
```

that works fine. But I wonder if there is any better Pythonic way of doing the same thing?

What I found the most similar to my problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989403/mean-of-non-zero-elements-in-3d-array).  But I don't quite understand the answer explained in a slightly different context.

Comment: As this is fully-working code; this might be better placed on http://codereview.stackexchange.com (please delete this question if you decide to post there)

Comment: Thank you JeffUK, I was not aware that there is another appropriate site to ask a working code. As I have already received 2 answers to this post, I will leave my post here this time. But I will go to the other site from next time!

Comment: good call!  They are the real experts at code review you will get a lot of great pointers over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method to filter out the `0`s from the arrays.

Here is a list comprehension approach:

```
import numpy as np

a_3d_array = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
                        [1, 1, 1],
                        [2, 2, 2],
                        [0, 3, 3],
                        [0, 0, 4]],
                       [[1, 2, 3],
                        [2, 2, 2],
                        [3, 3, 3],
                        [0, 4, 4],
                        [0, 0, 5]]])

aveCol = np.array([[np.mean(list(filter(None, a_3d_array[n,:,j]))[-2:]) for j in range(3)] for n in range(2)])
print(aveCol)
```

Output:

```
[[1.5 2.5 3.5] 
 [2.5 3.5 4.5]]
```

---

Note from @gboffi: For efficiency, use

```
aveCol = np.array([[sum([i for i in a_3d_array[n,:,j] if i][-2:])/2 for j in range(3)] for n in range(2)])
```

instead of

```
aveCol = np.array([[np.array([i for i in a_3d_array[n,:,j] if i][-2:]) for j in range(3)] for n in range(2)])
```

Comment: Hi, I eventually found that your solution is actually the fastest, as long as you use `sum()/2` in place of `np.mean` — I guess that the overhead of the Numpy function is simply out of place when taking the mean of 2 numbers…

Comment: Thank you for all your advices. I truly appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR As far as I can tell, [Ann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64987888/2749397) is the fastest

---

Each `m` is a *n×i* 2D array, next we take a `r`ow of its transpose, i.e., the "column" on which to perform the computation — on this "column" we discard ALL the zeros, we sum the last two non zero elements and take the mean

```
In [17]: np.array([[sum(r[r!=0][-2:])/2 for r in m.T] for m in a])
Out[17]: 
array([[1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
       [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]])
```

---

*Edit1*

It looks like it's faster than your loop

```
In [19]: %%timeit
    ...: avg = np.zeros([2,3])
    ...: for n in range(2):
    ...:     for j in range(3):
    ...:         temp = a[n,:,j]
    ...:         nz = temp[np.nonzero(temp)]
    ...:         avg[n, j] = np.mean(nz[-2:])
95.1 µs ± 596 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit np.array([[sum(r[r!=0][-2:])/2 for r in m.T] for m in a])
45.5 µs ± 394 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

*Edit2*

```
In [22]: %timeit np.array([[np.mean(list(filter(None, a[n,:,j]))[-2:]) for j in range(3)] for n in range(2)])
145 µs ± 689 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

*Edit3*

```
In [25]: %%timeit
    ...: i = np.indices(a.shape)
    ...: i[:, a == 0] = -1
    ...: i = np.sort(i, axis=2)
    ...: i = i[:, :, -2:, :]
    ...: a[tuple(i)].mean(axis=1)
64 µs ± 239 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

*Edit4* ***Breaking News Info***

The culprit in Ann's answer is `np.mean`!!

```
In [29]: %timeit np.array([[sum(list(filter(None, a[n,:,j]))[-2:])/2 for j in range(3)] for n in range(2)])
32.7 µs ± 111 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indices of your array `a`, mark zero items by a negative number, sort, limit and then use the result as an index:

```py
i = np.indices(a.shape)
i[:, a == 0] = -1
i = np.sort(i, axis=2)
i = i[:, :, -2:, :]
a[tuple(i)].mean(axis=1)
# array([[1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
#        [2.5, 3.5, 4.5]])
```